# .htaccess file load index several times

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a `INSERT` query into my index.php and when I load some page of site, i realize that query is executed 3 to 5 times.

Here is mod_rewrite of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php is my dispatcher. I get first word after backslash and require the page corresponding to this word.
I tried several different `RewriteRule`-s and the query began to run once(with this snippet

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index\.php/$1 [QSA,L]`),

but when I try to load URI like this http://www.example.com/somepage/param1 i got 404 error.
What's wrong with my .htaccess?

Comment: Check the access log and confirm that the file was requested 3 to 5 times.

Comment: Add a rule to check that the requested URI does not have `index.php` in it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`

Comment: @zerkms I checked the access log and there is only one request to page.  Interestingly, when i use snippet with one execution, the loading time of page is decreased

Comment: @InTERpLAY if there is one entry in access log - the file was requested once.

Comment: @zerkms I think that i have a favicon issue. I changed my index with empty page and check out the log. On 1 page load i got 4 request one header and 3 favicon.ico. I change code to this `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)` and may be it works :)